# Notepad++ saved ISO-8859-1 character as 256+ UTF-8 - how to retrieve original character?

Tags: string, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, notepad++

I created a txt file with Notepad++, put some text in there and saved it.

As I reopened the file, some characters changed to thai characters:

```
ร //Unicode \u0E23
ถ //Unicode \u0E16
```

The problem is, they are part of a cryptic password which I saved there because I couldn't memorize it immediately. And changing the encoding in Notepad++ to "UTF-8" or "UTF-8 without DOM" didn't do anything.

Is there a way to retrieve the original characers? I'd be really grateful!

Kind regards,
JaySon

Answer (score 0):

The issue is quite simple, you saved the document as ISO-8859-1. When Notepad++ came to open it, it guessed the format was UTF-8. There's no way for Notepad++ to know the difference.

All you needed to do was: Goto "Encoding"->"UTF-8". This changes the way Notepad++ **interprets** the file. The "Convert" methods will write what you have on the screen to file using the specified encoding. This is where conversion back becomes problematic.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm aware of that and if that had worked out, I wouldn't have asked this question in the first place.